# Hive Windowing Additonal output

Tags: hive

Given the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE dat (dt STRING, uxt BIGINT, temp FLOAT, city STRING);
INSERT INTO dat VALUES
('1/1/2000 0:53', 946687980, 100, 'A'),
('1/1/2000 0:59', 946688340, 28.9, 'A'),
('1/1/2000 13:54', 946734840, -1, 'A'),
('1/1/2000 13:55', 946734900, 30.9, 'A'),
('1/1/2000 22:53', 946767180, 30.9, 'A'),
('1/1/2000 22:59', 946767540, 30, 'A'),
('1/2/2000 1:25', 946776300, 121, 'A'),
('1/2/2000 1:53', 946777980, 28.9, 'A'),
('1/2/2000 2:53', 946781580, 28.9, 'A'),
('1/3/2000 1:53', 946864380, 10, 'A'),
('1/3/2000 11:20', 946898400, 15.1, 'A'),
('1/3/2000 11:53', 946900380, 18, 'A'),
('1/3/2000 21:00', 946933200, 17.1, 'A'),
('1/3/2000 21:53', 946936380, 16, 'A');
```

I am using some windowing functions to find maxtemp, mintemp, etc. for every 24-hour period:

```
select dt, uxt, maxtemp, mintemp, ABS(maxtemp - mintemp) as tempDiff, city
from(
select dt, uxt, max(temp) over (w) as maxtemp, min(temp) over (w) as 
mintemp, city
from dat
WINDOW w as (partition by city order by uxt range between CURRENT ROW and 
86400 FOLLOWING))t1
order by tempDiff desc;
```

This gives me the following output (first row):

```
dt                   uxt      maxtemp   mintemp tempdiff    city
2000-01-01 13:54    946734840   121.0   -1.0    122.0        A
```

I would like to add the 'dt' for when the maxtemp occurred to the output and struggling to find a solution.

The first row of the output would look something like this:

```
dt                   uxt      maxtemp   mintemp tempdiff    city   maxdt   
2000-01-01 13:54    946698780   121        -1    122         A     '2000-01-02 01:25'
```

Using the first_value query:

```
select dt
  ,uxt
  ,max(temp) over w as maxtemp
  ,min(temp) over w as mintemp
  ,abs(max(temp) over w - min(temp) over w) as tempDiff
  ,first_value(dt) over (w order by temp desc) as maxdt
  ,city
from dat
order by tempDiff desc
WINDOW w as (partition by city order by uxt 
         range between CURRENT ROW and 86400 FOLLOWING);
```

is producing this output (first two rows):

```
dt               uxt        maxtemp mintemp tempdiff maxdt          city
1/1/2000 0:59    946688340  121.0   -1.0    122.0    1/2/2000 1:53  A
1/1/2000 0:53    946687980  121.0   -1.0    122.0    1/1/2000 0:53   A
```

It is giving a maxtemp that is not in the 24 hour date range. Also, the 2nd row the temp for 1/1/2000 0:53 is not 121.0

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by including the following `first_value` window function in the inner query.

```
first_value(dt) over (partition by city order by uxt,temp desc 
                      range between CURRENT ROW and 7200 FOLLOWING)
```

Also note the query can be simplified to (eliminating a sub-query as there is no need for one in this case)

```
select dt
      ,uxt
      ,max(temp) over w as maxtemp
      ,min(temp) over w as mintemp
      ,abs(max(temp) over w - min(temp) over w) as tempDiff
      ,first_value(dt) over (w order by temp desc) as maxdt
      ,city
from dat
WINDOW w as (partition by city order by uxt 
             range between CURRENT ROW and 7200 FOLLOWING)
```

Comment: Thanks Vamsi, I was not aware of this function... unfortunately it does not appear to work when I have date intervals that do not fall exactly on the 2-hour mark. I updated my op and changed the data and time period to 24 hours. I am getting odd values when I use the first_value(dt) over (w order by temp desc).... Also, thanks for pointing out the simplification.